# Creating alias in Conemu

Tags: conemu

Is it possible to create alias for ConEmu?
Also in linux, bash terminal have .bashrc file, what is similar to ConEmu?

Thanks

Comment: I believe that aliases must be supported by your shell rather than terminal. E.g. mentioned `.bashrc` belong to bash (shell) but not terminal. And you may use bash with ConEmu too.

Comment: Yes your are right.
Sorry for this. Actually I am on window. Can you please help me out how to create this on window cmd (which I now think will be used by conemu).

Comment: If powershell is an option, you can define aliases in your profile file

Answer (score 23, accepted):

### New answer

In latest ConEmu builds there is an [Environment](https://conemu.github.io/en/SettingsEnvironment.html) settings page. You may set there environment variables **and** aliases for cmd.exe. One line set one alias. Example:

```
alias cdd=cd /d $1
```

### Old answer

You may use `doskey` for creating aliases. Next 
example supposed your installation folder is `C:\Program Files\ConEmu`) and your shell is `cmd.exe`.

Create following batch file `C:\Program Files\ConEmu\ConEmu\aliases.cmd`:

```
@echo off
doskey /EXENAME=cmd.exe cdd=cd /d $1
```

Start your shell in ConEmu as followed (for example, Settings -> Startup -> Command line):

```
cmd /k "%ConEmuBaseDir%\aliases.cmd"
```

Now you may type in prompt something like this

```
cdd D:\AnyFolder
```

Comment: I would suggest to use `cmd /k "%userprofile%\.conemu\cmdinit.cmd"`, to stick with lastest version of conemu and keep your files on your side. See [doc](http://conemu.github.io/en/CmdPrompt.html) and [default file](https://github.com/Maximus5/ConEmu/blob/master/Release/ConEmu/CmdInit.cmd)

Comment: I believe using Environment page is much more handy nowadays.

Comment: works like a charm!

Answer (score 4):

You could use [TCC/LE](http://jpsoft.com/tccle-cmd-replacement.html) with ConEmu. It's a free cmd.exe replacement and, unlike Powershell, is backward compatible. You can use the `ALIAS` command to create and manage aliases and `TCSTART` to do a similar thing .bashrc does.

- [`ALIAS` help](http://jpsoft.com/help/index.htm?alias.htm)
- [`TCSTART` help](http://jpsoft.com/help/index.htm?autobatch.htm)

Answer (score 1):

For reference purpose...

**Multiple arguments:** `$*`

**Source:** [Settings Environment](http://conemu.github.io/en/SettingsEnvironment.html)